# SKScene stays in memory after dismissing its parent view controller

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift4

When testing my app I realised that going to the view controller which presents my scene and back again increases the used space in memory. So I run instruments to learn what wasn’t deallocated. I found that there was some instances of my scene taking up space. How can I fix it?

I have a property in my scene class to access its view controller (which I defined as weak to avoid a retain cycle)
The concerning lines in my scene class are:

```
weak var viewController: MyViewControllerClass?
func exitFunction () {
viewController.dismiss(animated: true , completion: nil)
self.view!.presentScene(nil)
}
```

Comment: You have a retain cycle going on.  Probably a block is holding onto scene.

Comment: That’s what I think, but can’t find which part of my code has produced it

Answer (score 0):

All your scenes should belong to the same view controller, that is to say in a sprite kit game there is only one view controller.

You should define your scenes and the SKView to present them on in this view controller like so:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var skView: SKView?
    var mainMenu: MainMenu?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        skView = self.view as! SKView?
    }
```

Inside your scene make sure you are deallocating your resources properly:

```
override func willMove(from view: SKView) {
    removeAllChildren()
}

deinit {
    //Deallocate your resources here
}
```

WillMove is called each time you move from the scene to another.

Finally when you show your scenes from inside your viewController class make sure you deallocate old ones first:

```
func showMainMenu(_ notification: Notification) {
    deallocScenes()
    mainMenu = MainMenu(fileNamed: "MainMenu")
    mainMenu?.scaleMode = .fill
    skView!.presentScene(mainMenu)
}

func deallocScenes(){
    mainMenu = nil
    levelSelection = nil
    credits = nil
}
```

Comment: yeah just remove all scene children, should do the trick

scene?.removeAllActions()
scene?.removeAllChildren()

Comment: remove all actions only removes actions on the scene, not on all the children

Comment: I don’t have multiple scenes, just one. I do need multiple view controllers, so I have. I’ve tried removing action from the scene and its children, stopping the core motion updates but I still have memory leaks.